# Intentionally Recreating a Multithreading SQL Error

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, oracle

So I have a batch processor which is multithreaded that takes some values and inserts them into an Oracle DB. I'm receiving reports that this processor is logging `Unique Constraint` errors.

This is the query that the processor is using to insert:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_T 

(VALUE_A_PK, VALUE_B_PK, VALUE_C, VALUE_D, VALUE_E, VALUE_F, VALUE_G, VALUE_H, VALUE_I, VALUE_J) 

      SELECT ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? FROM DUAL 

               WHERE NOT EXISTS

                        (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_T WHERE 

                         VALUE_A_PK= ? AND VALUE_B_PK = ?);
```

I know of ways to fix this, but first I need to recreate the error to prove that I've actually fixed it.
Despite feeding multiple duplicate records to the processor, I cannot manually get the error to resurface.

It seems almost certain to me that this is a multithreading issue where multiple threads are attempting to insert a new record at the same time.

Is there a reliable way to force more than one thread to execute at exactly the same time? If I could do that, then it seems like I should be able to get the error pop back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to fire two statements in two sessions at the *exact* same time. Tools like DBMS_SCHEDULER could perhaps reliably start two processes within a second, but to imitate primary key errors for one-row inserts you'll need a much higher precision.

It might be easier to run the statement in two separate sessions in a loop, and just wait until one of them fails. I've done this several times before to reproduce intermittent problems.

Run this pseudo-code in two or more sessions and wait for an error:

```
begin
    for i in 1 .. 1000000 loop
        INSERT INTO TABLE_T ...
    end loop;
end;
/
```